# Should I be using env() outside my config files?

Tags: php, laravel

I stumbled across this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#configuration-caching in the documentation and it confused me a bit.

When I want an environment variable I use the env() function to return what I want. According to the above link it says I should be using the config() function instead to ensure that on production I am accessing the values through a cache.

e.g. These both return the same thing

`env('APP_URL')`

vs

`config('app.url')`

So should I be using `config()` or `env()` inside my app?

I assume that if I add a new env variable I will also need to update my config files?

Comment: You can use the `env()` helper anywhere in your code; I use it often to check the `APP_ENV` value to determine if I should or should not do something (like sending emails; I don't bother with it on `APP_ENV=local`)

Comment: Thanks Tim, however I think Alexey has the right answer.

Comment: Not a problem; I was unaware of config caching, might have to update my use cases moving forward.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should never use `env()` in the code directly. It's a good practice to use `config()`. In `config` files use `env()` to get the data from `.env` file.

In this case, you can easily override config values at runtime or during testing.

You also can use config caching.

> To give your application a speed boost, you should cache all of your configuration files into a single file using the `config:cache` Artisan command.

Another reason is [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#configuration-caching):

> You should typically run the php artisan config:cache command as part of your production deployment routine. If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files.

Comment: So to clarify If I want to add a new variable in my env file that I will access in my code I should also add a reference to it in my config folder and call config()?

Comment: @Kyslik that's true. Thanks.

Comment: @hdifen Am on the side of the camp that considers adding values in config and .env as being stupid. Developers could make unforeseen blunders and expose their app credentials in production when they do not know how to link the secret variable required in application code to the config file and then back to the .env file. 

I think it defeats the entire purpose but there's nothing we can do.

Comment: @MosesNdeda I see your point however you could make the argument `Developers could make unforeseen blunders and expose their app credentials` for anything.  Just depends how many barriers you put up I guess.  If you have an app that needs insane security you can go down the encryption route.  Take a listen to https://www.phproundtable.com/episode/securely-managing-secrets-in-php. They go into detail on this.