# Didn't get env file value in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, environment

I am facing one weird issue in laravel. I am fetching a value from env file into my controller. but I didn't get any value from my env file.

Key name in env file.

```
MYKEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Getting key value from my controller file like this. My laravel version in 5.6

```
$key = env('MYKEY');
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try resetting laravel cache by `php artisan config:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Did you have any other env values? Try to surround value in quotes

Comment: It's better practice to use config() rather then env().

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929747/should-i-be-using-env-outside-my-config-files

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` should be enough to get the new value (config gets cached for faster loading, should run this whenever you make changes to .env)

Comment: add key and value in `.env` file not in `.env.example` file

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

```
php artisan cache:clear

$key = env('MYKEY');
```

**OR**

You can set your `env` variable in config file

```
config/app.php
'mykey' => env('MYKEY'),
```

then set your config variable in your code like:

```
use Config;

$key = Config:get('app.mykey');
```