# Update .env value using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, laravel-5.8

I know some of your might think that this will lead to security issue.

But ...

I only want to update only `2` specific flags, because sometimes, I want to see the reports, and sometimes, I don't. If I have a way to update those flags -- I can just hook up a route to toggle that functionality - via Apple iPhone Shortcut whenever I want to see reports via EMAIL or SMS.

---

## I've tried

created a route

```
Route::get('/env/{flag}/{value}','GeneralController@envUpdate');
```

called it

```
http://localhost/env/MAIL_REPORT/false
```

that will trigger this function

```
public function setEnv($key, $val)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');

    if (file_exists($path)) {

        file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
            $key . '=' . env($key), $key . '=' . $val, file_get_contents($path)
        ));
    }
}

public function envUpdate($flag,$value)
{
    //dd($flag,$value);
    $allow_flags = ["MAIL_REPORT", "SMS_REPORT"];

    if (in_array($flag, $allow_flags))
    {
        setEnv((string)$flag, (string)$value);
        return env(env((string)$flag));
    }

}
```

I kept getting `true` because in my .env does not seem to be updated

```
MAIL_REPORT=true
```

I suppose to have `MAIL_REPORT=false`

**Note** : I already ran : `sudo chmod 777 .env`

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: Is it normal to have two nested function definitions? Also, in Laravel (and in Symfony) the .env is read and the variables are set as environment variables, but calling `setEnv()` will not update the file. You'll probably have to parse the file as text or to use a library that does that.

Comment: Ok, let me pull out the function and try this again.

Comment: Why would you want to programatically update the `.env` file? This is really bad practice!

Comment: I only want to update only specific flag, because sometime, I want to see the report, sometime, I don't. If I have a way to do that I can just hook up a route to trigger that function - via iPhone Apple Shortcut whenever I want to see reports via EMAIL.

Comment: @Jerodev I will only only 2 flags, to do that. I will do a check in that function. I would never in a million year open this route to the world, but that is my next step.

Comment: @Jerodev : I updated my functions to only allow 2 flags, you see what I mean now. I don't plan to open it for all the flags.

Comment: I still don’t think that updating .env file is a good idea since you’ll have to grant write permission to php (Normally it’ll be read-only). How about using key-value database instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change the environment variables I would suggest to just change your `.env` file and re-cache your config (if in production). Your current implementation might be pretty sensitive for security issues.

If you do want to change your env variables programmatically at run time you can always use the `config()` helper method.

```
config(['mailing. reporting' => false]);
```

This is also documented in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#accessing-configuration-values).

### Edit

So I think you're implementation of the env variables might be a little incorrect. The environment variables itself SHOULD NOT change at run time in your applications. The only place where the `env()` function should be called is in the config files (found in the `config` directory). So what you want is to create a new key in your `config/mailing.php` config file.

```
'reporting' => env('MAIL_REPORT', false),
```

Now whenever you need to set this variable to true you can either change the `.env` file or use the first given example (`config(['mailing. reporting' => false]);`).

Read more about it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#environment-configuration).

Comment: Why `mailing.report` ? my flag spell like this `MAIL_REPORT`

Comment: It's just a guess on how your config might look like. Where do you use the `MAIL_REPORT` env variable? I suppose in one of your config files?

Comment: i've tried this : https://i.imgur.com/QxPIEHb.png , I still get true. I should see it updated to `false`

Comment: Can you help me see that it updated ? what did I miss ?

Comment: `MAIL_REPORT` is one of the key `flag` in my `.env` file

Comment: I don't want to hook it up to my `mail.php` - I think you missed my point.

Comment: The goal of this post is to update the value of `.env` - that's IT. disregard what that flag will do in Laravel application.

Comment: My answer will do EXACTLY what you need. However, you need to change the way of thinking . You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47929765/2783759) or read [this blog post](https://barryvanveen.nl/blog/23-laravel-configuration-the-right-way).

Comment: @kyo it's a bad idea to change .env as Dees mentioned, if you need similar behaviour, change the mail.php as he also mentioned, which is the best solution.  in stackoverflow , you should give an exact & CORRECT answer, the exact answer you want is WRONG and he's answer fixes the probleme.